# How to add and execute my own lambda function within the serverless-framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

How do I add my own lambda without going to AWS console manually and, most importantly, how do I call it from my React app?

Currently, if I want to execute my own lambda function, I go to AWS console and create it there manually. Clearly, there is a way to do this locally in VS Code, since serverless-framework has created its functions already using the *fullstack-app* deployment.

This is my current Lambda function (send an email from contact form using Amazon SES) created in AWS using console.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({region: 'us-east-1'});
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
     var params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [`${event.toEmail}`]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {Html: { Data: `${event.body}`}
            },
            Subject: { Data: `${event.subject}`}
        },
        Source: `${event.fromEmail}`
    };

     ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
        callback(null, {err: err, data: data});
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            context.succeed(event);
        }
    });
};
```

I have created a REST API for it in AWS and I call it from my React app with axios:

```
  axios.post(`https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/contactFormSend`, email)
  .then(res => {console.log(res)})
```

My goal is to not create the lambda function manually in AWS console, but write it locally using serverless-framework architecture and find a way to call it.

I have looked everywhere, but I feel like I have missed something very important during my learning about serverless-framework architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add my own lambda without going to AWS console manually and,
> most importantly ?

I hope you have serverless.yml file with your function config. Here is a template with possible configs https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

If everything is setup deploying is super easy , just by using `serverless deploy`

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying/

Here is a very simple one from serverless examples - https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api

> How do I call it from my React app ?

You need an exposed public endpoint either you take directly the one generated by `API Gateway` or you create custom domain and map it to your existing domain.

Comment: Thank you for all the links, but I still don't really understand how to call a custom Lambda from my React app after it's been uploaded to AWS using the serverless-framework.

I can figure out how to call a seperate Lambda function that I have created myself in AWS console (as per my example), but not how to call just a part of the function that was uploaded by the serverless-framework. What am I missing? There must be a gap in my understanding on how serverless calls the lambda functions exactly.

Comment: If you plan to call AWS Lambda via API Gateway you only need a simple http call. 
Make sure your setup if correct, open API Gateway and try the call there first after it passes use it from react. 
Note: Additional CORS could be enabled for your case.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, but is there a **code example** of how to exactly call the serverless created function from an app like React? 

I am a frontend developer only dipping my fingers in the backend work currently. A simple example of exactly how to call a serverless function from React would be most helpful.

Comment: You'd call it exactly like you've shown in your example code - with `fetch` or `axios` or some other library you choose. You should have an `http event` described in your function in the `serverless.yml` file, which creates a API endpoint that you can call from the frontend - like this - https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-rest-api/serverless.yml. Then the usage example is here - https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api except you'd use `fetch or axios` instead of `curl`